# Most Needed Open Source Project

Tags: open-source

A few questions on the site have mentioned the need for more open source projects. I agree and wonder what frameworks should be developed.

I'll start the list.

- A geometry kernel, including
  serialization (JSON, binary,
  compressed binary), tailored for
  OpenGL/DirectX
- Gesture recognition

Comment: Not a real question.

Comment: @FreshCode: Hence the "Community Wiki" flag. While this site doesn't have exact guidelines for community wikis yet, this falls well within the boundaries of the flag on other SE sites, e.g. MathOverflow (http://mathoverflow.net/faq#communitywiki).

Comment: If you are starting a list question it would be better if your answers are in an answer instead of the question so they can be voted on separately.

Answer (score 43):

I've already complained about this in another question, but having open digital distribution systems would be glorious. This encompasses both patching systems and end-user marketplace type things. Steam handles a lot of this, but is far from an open platform. Even if it wasn't a single shared marketplace like Steam is (or how phone marketplaces are going), having a solution you could easily rebrand and deploy for yourself would be a huge step forward (assuming people actually did things like submit patches upstream and all that FOSS goodness).

Comment: I've spent the last two years here working on our in-house system, so I'm probably a bit biased.

Comment: To be fair, this would be exceptional valuable even outside of the gaming domain!

Comment: @Coderanger Open to what end? I am working on some tools like this for my website, and I would love to pick your brain.

Comment: @Noctrine My email is noah@<my website>, feel free to drop me a line :-)

Comment: Wasn't that what Launchpad+APT was supposed to be, and it just turned into a baroque nightmare?

Comment: Pure software distribution is a sorely under-loved area of open source software. I'd gladly dedicate my time to a project such as this. It's something an entire sector of the industry would appreciate. I know some of the guys at Mozilla have been looking at doing something very similar for 'web apps'.

@Joe That just made me think of Sony LaunchPad @.@ urgh... nasty thing. Launchpad looks quite broad... handling development + bug tracking + hosting. Not just distribution.

Comment: what is wrong with actually using steam/steamworks?

Comment: Not available to everyone, can't be rebranded, bad support for large updates unless you use their file archives.

Comment: Would this hypothetical open-source distribution system include **DRM**? That's really the whole point of Steam - an online distributor that maintains *maximum control* over the delivered software - which is the *antithesis* of open-source, of course (of course...). (Note, I don't have a problem with DRM, if done reasonably un-obtrusively/non-destructively).

Comment: Steam DRM is only enabled by the choice of the publisher. For example, once you download any of our (Cryptic) games, you can uninstall Steam and never use it again. Also keep in mind that I am talking about the platform itself being open, not the games (though obviously have a DRM-free option for open games would be preferable).

Answer (score 5):

Graphics driver develpers. Without working graphics drivers other game-related projects are irrelevant.

AMD and NVIDIA actually do make usable drivers, but I'm talking about open-source drivers. Mesa only supports OpenGL 2.1.

edit: This answer is only applicable to GNU/Linux.

Comment: Why is it so important for Linux to have open source drivers, if the proprietary drivers are usable? Putting the ideology aside, what relevance does it have to games?

Comment: @Kylotan: not all GPUs have proprietary drivers available. Intel is one of them, and their hardware, while not very fast, is fast enough to play many games. Gamers would enjoy faster/less buggy drivers. Reporting bugs is not enough, Mesa/Intel need more developers. To get them, they need better documentation.

Comment: @Kylotan The proprietary drivers are a huge joke at best. The performance and OpenGL support is terrible and spotty, especially in ATI's drivers. It seems like their Linux drivers were only created because somebody twisted their arm.

Comment: @Kylotan: Because you could have a savvy community bettering the drivers, instead of being at the mercy of ATI/NVidia's ebb and flow feelings vis-a-vis the Linux community. Their focus, with good reason, is to support the Windows platform. Linux is, at best, secondary.

Comment: It will never happen. The corporate line is that they believe allowing the open-source community to build drivers exposes too many secrets to competitors.

Answer (score 4):

Not a software project, but a documentation one:

**A game technical quality checklist** (like trcs or tcrs)

Many a time the design of a production game has been affected by these quite important documents. Indie games need them as much as professional games developers do, as it's at least a simple assurance that you've done a reasonable job.

**Certification**

There couldn't be a certifying body, but it could be a self certifying thing to start with.

If the checklist was concise, it could more easily become a generally agreed upon checklist. Once agreed upon, it might then become reasonable for distributors to allow peer review to confirm or deny claims whereupon the information becomes part of the distributors basic information package about items in its store.

**Location**

Why not start one on the game dev wiki... http://wiki.gamedev.net/index.php/Main_Page
?

Comment: Obviously there can't really be a certifying body, nor are some of the TCRs from major platform holders relevant, but this is a really interesting idea. Do you know if anyone's done work on something like this?

Comment: There is the [evil checklist](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/help/peerreview_evilchecklist) for XBLIG games (and a corresponding not so evil checklist).

Comment: The not-so-evil checklist (http://creators.xna.com/en-us/help/peerreview_notsoevilchecklist) looks much more useful outside the world of XBLIG.

Answer (score 4):

A generic, cross-platform game editing tool that allows you to edit game content (2D and 3D) for any game engine. It can be supplemented by editing & export plugins for a specific game engine, or for a specific game genre's editing needs (eg. 3D platform game editor, 2D user interface editor, 3D tilemap editor, etc).

Rationale: most open source game engines do not provide editing tools. Most existing game editing tools are proprietary and only work with the vendor's game engine (Torque, Unity, Shiva, etc.), or have a limited use (2D Tilemap editing). If you switch engines or platforms, you usually have to leave whichever tools you were working with behind and either learn or even write a new tool, or work without any tools at all.

What do you think of this idea? Do you think it's desireable? And would it be feasible?

Comment: It's feasible. And it exists. It's called 3ds Max (or XSI, or Blender, or...).

Comment: Those are 3D modellers, not game content editors. They have been, shall I say, abused for editing some games but other than throwing something together real quick they are a pain to make actual game levels/worlds with.

Comment: Okay, try Syntensity, Tiled, etc. There are other, more specialized editors. If you are looking for something as easy as the editor in Spore or ModNation, then you are looking at something that tends to be too one-game specific.

Answer (score 3):

A Geometry kernel also begs for an Animation Kernel, including blending.

Answer (score 2):

A good Flash player, since Adobe seems uninterested / underfunded in really working on theirs on non-Windows OSs, and the existing implementations are lacking (even e.g. ScaleForm has significant problems being "proper Flash" as designers/artists expect).

Comment: See also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/hardware-acceleration-for-the-flash-player

Answer (score 1):

I guess that open service for custom avatar sprites would be useful especially with the growth of online and mobile HTML5-based games. I described the idea [here](http://aaiddennium.com/blog/2010/open-gaming-avatar-service-required/).

Answer (score 1):

[EA STL](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html) (or equivalent).

Comment: Just wondering, why? The basic approach of EASTL is detailed more than enough in the paper to copy the parts you need; the particular implementation details of EASTL are now several years old and there are probably better ways to do it on newer C++ compilers; and many of the extensions they talk about are available in Boost (e.g. boost::intrusive::list) or tr1 (e.g. standard unordered_map). There are a few useful things left in it, but I'd never say it's the _most_ needed open source project.

Comment: Why duplicate the effort? Why not benefit from peer review? Boost and TR1 do nothing to improve the brain-damaged allocator design, for one. Many of the proposed changes could be adopted by the STL and the STL would be better for it. But that will never happen.

Comment: Well, it looks like your dream came true! http://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL

Answer (score 1):

An stl-like collection of templated datastructures often used in games:

- [hierarchical] state machines
- quad-/octrees
- bsp trees
- sphere trees
- kd trees
- [any other useful spatial datastructure not listed]
- resource managers
- linear/pool/other allocators
- timers
- decision trees

It would be really nice to have theese available in an easy to use form that's known to be well tested and stable.

While open source implementations of some of the data structures listed exist, they're often not templated to use any data type (e.g. you're often forced to use yet another matrix/vector structure), not in a usable state, dead or lack peer review and testing.

Answer (score 0):

Networking.

For starters, a good system for NAT (Network Address Traversal) and routing, to combat any woes with firewalls and proxies. PC gamers should never have to deal with forwarding ports or anything similar.

Even better: An open-source, distributed multiplayer game network (eg. Battle.net, Xbox Live, PSN...). This would essentially be a protocol that anyone can implement, and anyone can run a server - they just communicate with each other to pass around information about who can be found where. Similar to distributed social networks (eg. Diaspora), this keeps any one party from having control, whilst allowing any indie game to seamlessly integrate into it.

Imagine if you could just add your friends as 'friends', and then any game you ever played you could just invite them straight away, no ip addresses, no id lookups, you just take them with you. Basically what B.net/XBL/PSN do already, but open and free for all!

Comment: Your second suggestion is a pretty trivial layer over XMPP, the problem isn't getting it made, it's getting everyone to support it.

Answer (score -2):

A real MMO platform, ie. one that supplies the middleware, lobby functions, etc, into which you can plug in your engine.

Comment: -1, there is no way this is the most needed project, given that nearly every other project suggested here is a prerequisite of it.

Comment: Every? There are lots of decent open networking libraries (you don't need a distributed version), open modellers exist already (Blender), I don't see the need for EA STL, game engines exist, etc. The only viable competitor project IMO is the digital distribution which would be cool. I can understand not voting for it, but downvote? Much of gaming is happening online, yet there is not even anything close to a viable, open platform for the ecosystem around an MMO.

Comment: Yes, _nearly_ every. You'd need a patcher, a content editor, and geometry and animation kernels. You'd need some kind of social features for your network. You'd also need a standard library that works for games; EA STL is one such beast, though you could find another or write your own.

Comment: Content editor: Blender, Tiled, Syntensity. Kernels: not sure exactly what you mean here. Kernel is an overloaded term. Game dev "standard library": Lots of different languages and different game types. One library to handle them all? Really? Lastly, "social features" is exactly what I am proposing as part of a platform for online gaming.